# Passing instance variable to js.erb file (Rails 3 / jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, partials

I have an "index.html.erb" file with the following:

> <%= render @users %>

This renders "_user.html.erb" and outputs a button for performing a certain action on each user:

> <%= link_to "action", action_path(user), :id => "#{user.id}_action", :remote => true) %>

I've set up my User controller to respond to the AJAX request by looking at "action.js.erb".

In order to perform javascript methods on particular users within the partial, and I'd like to know how instance variables from my partial (such as user.id) can be passed into or accessed within the js.erb file, for instance:

```
$("#{@user.id}_action").toggle();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You access the information in your `*.js.erb`-files just like in your `*.html.erb`-files, using `@users` or other instance variables declared in the controller:

```
$("#<%= @user.id %>_action").toggle();
```

Comment: please see edit. declaring @user.id within the js.erb as such isn't being recognized.

Comment: awesome. works with a minor edit to declare the css id using the "#" prefix. (please make the edit in your answer, it won't let me do it). thanks!

Comment: I got `nil` on @user or @whatever.

Answer (score 6):

there's an excellent gem called gon that might simplify and organize things quite a bit:
https://github.com/gazay/gon/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Perfect!! Exactly what I was looking for!!