# Instance variables in controller passed to bootstrap file input plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using bootstrap3 and a particular plugin for bootstrap called [file-input](http://plugins.krajee.com/file-input).  I'm using file-input and paperclip to attach a picture of a restaurant to my Restaurant model.

One of the things I would like to do is have the ability for my users, when editing a restaurant image, to be able to see the old restaurant image (which is stored in `@restaurant.image.url`).  After reading the documentation, I found that I can set a default image to file-input by passing in a source like so:

```
initialPreview: [
    "<img src='/images/desert.jpg' class='file-preview-image' alt='Desert' title='Desert'>",
    "<img src='/images/jellyfish.jpg' class='file-preview-image' alt='Jelly Fish' title='Jelly Fish'>",
],
```

What I'm stuck on is how do I get my `@restaurant.image.url` into the src attribute of a javascript array, that I can then pass on into the file-input plugin.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003501/passing-instance-variable-to-js-erb-file-rails-3-jquery) question and it made it seem like if I turn my `restaurant.js` file into a `restaurant.js.erb` file I can just use ruby expressions.

**javascript**

```
("#image_upload").fileinput( initialPreview: ["<img src='<%= @restaurant.image.url %>' class='file-preview-image'>",]);
```

But `@restaurant` is blank in my javascript file.  Anyone know why?

I am using rails 4, I don't know if that is the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, files located in the asset folder don’t have access to instance variables defined in the controller.  However, views invoked by your controller do. One simple solution (although rails purists might behead me) would be to inline the javascript directly into your form partial.

in your `_form.html.erb`

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
      img_source = "#{defined?(@restaurant) && @restaurant.image.exists? ? @restaurant.image.url : image_url('default_image.jpg')}"
      $("#image_upload").fileinput( initialPreview: ["<img src='"+img_source+"' class=\'file-preview-image\'>"]);
});
</script>
```

Note: I did add a default image (since you are using paperclip); modify accordingly.

More complicated solutions might involve gems such as [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) which can help you pass variables to javascript functions.

Comment: If I were to put the javascript in a partial, could that be done?  Would I have to put that in the views folder, or could I put it in the assets folder.